# Generate Signed APK gives an error in Android Studio 3.4

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Build APK and run application on external device work properly, but When I am trying to generate signed APK I got the error message

> Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.4.

Here is my Project `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        //mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

some of articles suggest to change `classpath` version but I think 3.4.2 is the latest version of gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By updating my android studio to 3.5, problem was fixed. I don't know the reason. this one was my last chance

Answer (score 0):

You should put `google()` as the first repo inside `buildscript{}`, i.e.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() //// <--- here
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. as I checked, most developer had this problem but the occurred problem was different for me. I did your suggestion before I write the question. thanks for your reply